# ?+* follows nothing in regexp

Tags: regex, perl, makefile, netcat

I am trying to compile netcat-0.7.1 on HP-UX, but I always get this error while making:

```
../doc/texi2pod.pl ./netcat.texi netcat.pod
/^([^=]+)(?:=(.+))?/: ?+* follows nothing in regexp at ../doc/texi2pod.pl line 48.
*** Error exit code 255
```

I opened texi2pod.pl  and try to put \Q \E like this: `/\Q^([^=]+)(?:=(.+))?\E/`
but it's not working. If someone could help me, it would be great.

Here is the code:

```
    ($flag, $value) = ($flag =~ /^([^=]+)(?:=(.+))?/);  
    die "no flag specified for -D\n" unless $flag ne "";  
    die "flags may only contain letters, digits, hyphens, dashes and underscores\n"
    unless $flag=~ /^[a-zA-ZO-9_-]+$/;
```

perl -v :

```
    Version 4.0
    Revision 4.0.1.8
```

Comment: `($flag, $value) = ($flag =~ /^([^=]+)(?:=(.+))?/);
 die "no flag specified for -D\n"
     unless $flag ne "";
 die "flags may only contain letters, digits, hyphens, dashes and underscores\n"`
I believe some of them are supposed to be literal. However, as I don't really understand Perl, it's hard to know which caracter is not supposed to be literal..

Comment: Never add code in the comments, use the `edit` button above.

Comment: That last die statement is incomplete. The first one is a nightmare, and whoever wrote it should be set on fire. It says "die if not $flag is not equal to the empty string". Who writes like that? Yoda? `if $flag eq ""`, I do believe is the equivalent.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just copy/paste these lines! Maybe you could tell Giovanni Giacobbi he is Yoda :)

Comment: Can you update your question with the results of running `perl -v`? I have a strong suspicion of what the issue is and that could confirm it.

Comment: Version 4.0 $$Revision 4.0.1.8 Patch level:36

Comment: Wow, really? You're running perl version 4.0?

Comment: Things that happened after your perl version was released: Bill Clinton became President of USA. The first (failed) bombing of World Trade Center. Microsoft releases Windows 3.11.

Comment: Haha ! It's my second week of internship and I am discovering things like that. Quite funny, but it is not that easy to tell them "Please update" when you are twenty and arrived one week ago ;)

Comment: @Q_C Ok, how about "Your software is arcane. It was released when Bill Clinton called the internet "The Information Super-Highway. Update it now, you morons." (You can skip the last part, since you're an intern.)

Comment: Hahaha, like it!! Thanks for the tips! And for the replies :) I wil **try** to update this week...

Comment: @TLP Well, he is running on HP/UX which had its last update back in 2007. And, HP/UX was never one that used the latest versions of third party utilities. He can download the [latest release of Perl for HP/UX](http://h21007.www2.hp.com/portal/site/dspp/menuitem.863c3e4cbcdc3f3515b49c108973a801/?ciid=9813daedbd9f4310VgnVCM200000a460ea10RCRD). That will bring him all the way up to version 5.8.8!

Comment: @DavidW. Whoa! Space-age technology. :) That's like upgrading from 5" floppies to 1Gb USB flash drives.

Comment: Believe me or not, this is a BIG  IT company :)
As we say in french :"Les cordonniers sont les plus mal chaussés"
Anyway, thanks for bringing me back around 2012!

Comment: @Q_C: it may be worth finding out who is older: you or that Perl version.

Comment: Wow, Perl 4?  And not even 4.0.36, but 4.0.1.  That's mind-boggling.  Let's check the ol' timeline... it was released almost exactly 21 years ago, on 1991-Apr-12.  Although the other comment seems to indicate that it might be 4.0.36 after all, in which case it was released on 1993-Feb-05.

Comment: ! I was born on 1991-Apr-18 ...

Comment: Well, then, @Q_C, happy birthday!

Answer (score 2):

Perl 5 added the `(?:PATTERN)` sequence to regular expressions, it was chosen because `(?` was invalid in all previous versions of Perl and would therefore not break currently working code. This also means that any code that uses it is not compatible with prior versions of Perl.

Very little modern Perl code will work with Perl 4. You will probably need to upgrade your Perl. This might require a cascading set of upgrades, like your C compiler, etc.

If you don't have some sort of security update arrangement with HP I'd be very concerned with connecting a system that old to the internet. If you don't have proprietary software that ties you to that old of a system you would probably be well served by upgrading to a much newer OS.

Comment: +1 for identifying the problem (though I had my suspicions, none included 20 year old versions of perl).

Comment: Yes, thanks for that!I like to understand why it doesn't work. I don't know if it will be possible for me - as a fresh trainee with no privileges - to upgrade their system. Someone told me I should develop my own program, instead of *trying* to use/install Netcat. It's quite annoying because it will take more time as I don't have any knowledge in network programming...but, after all, I am here to learn...

Comment: I'll second the +1. I thought there was a problem with regular expression compatibility, but I couldn't say what it was. I spent hours searching for Perl 5.000 release notes or a webpage that told me the difference between Perl 4 and early Perl 5, but I couldn't find any. I even checked the Internet Archives. Not much was on the web back then.

Answer (score 2):

First thing, you're going to have to update your version of Perl. Perl 4.0 is so obsolete, I can't even find any documentation on it.

You can update Perl from [HP/UX's Perl for HP/UX -11i](http://h21007.www2.hp.com/portal/site/dspp/menuitem.863c3e4cbcdc3f3515b49c108973a801/?ciid=9813daedbd9f4310VgnVCM200000a460ea10RCRD) page.

This update will move you from Perl 4.0 all the way up to Perl 5.8.8 which was release five or so years ago. Perl 5.8.8 is far from current, but at least it will bring your Perl into the 21st century.

**BRING ON THE JETPACKS AND FLYING CARS!**

Comment: Thanks, I will see what can I do there. I will try to make friends with the admin, send roses, and with the help of Yoda, force him to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

```
($flag, $value) = ($flag =~ /^([^=]+)(?:=(.+))?/);
```

It looks like texi2pod.pl is a very old script (last updated 2001?), and not written with `use strict`. This might make things iffy. I'm sure it's supposed to work, so the error may lay elsewhere in your setup.

However, this particular line seems to be designed to extract a flag and a value by simply splitting on the first equal sign `=`, so you may try to replace it with one of the following:

```
($flag, $value) = split /=/, $flag, 2;        # either just split with a limit
($flag, $value) = ($flag =~ /^([^=]+)=(.+)/); # or simplify regex
```

I think the problem is the last question mark, which I really don't understand the purpose of. In fact, the whole second part is odd. It *might* be some misguided attempt to allow empty values for the second capture.

**ETA:** With that said, update your perl version. If Ven'Tatsu is correct, its about 20 years old, and if it indeed works, its only by force of habit.

Comment: I'm trying your proposition. I also suspected that the problem came from this old version. However, I tried to update today but I had an error during it, so I asked my question here, thinking I still could use this old thing.

Comment: @Q_C It's quite astonishing, really. Around the time your perl version was published, I bought my first computer, it was a macintosh with 4Mb RAM and 120Mb harddrive, and a 25MHz CPU (IIRC). In other words, it is ***old***...

Comment: The (? syntax is used for extensions introduced in Perl 5.  Since (? was illegal in Perl 4, there was no backwards incompatibility problem with formerly-legal regexes suddenly getting a new interpretation.  (?: in particular means "group, but don't capture".  So you can group things together for matching purposes without taking up a capture group.